# C# formatting text in fixed column widths with wrapping

Tags: c#

I looked all over the place and didn't see an answer to this specific question...  I am writing a Windows Console app in C# and would like to take a set of strings and format them into fixed-width columns with wrapping.  The string that is returned should be padded with spaces and have a new line character at the end of each line.

Here's an example.  I have 3 text strings and I want to fit them into 3 fixed width columns with wrapping.

```
string text10 = "abcdefghij";
string text15 = "123456789012345";
string text6 = "zxywvu";
```

I want to format this into 3 columns with widths 4 - 10 - 5 (with a space between them).  As an example:

```
format(text10, test15, text5)
```

would return this:

```
abcd 1234567890 zxywv\n
efgh 13245      u    \n
ij                   \n
```

Does anyone know a simple way to do this with a .Net library or am I going to have to write a text formatter function for this stuff?

Comment: For what kind of application? Winforms, Webforms, MVC...?

Comment: My bad. Updated to mention that I'm working in C# and would like a string with the appropriate spaces and new line characters added in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly that kind of a problem that has as many answers as there are programmers. So I wanted to try too! If you need to change widths of the columns or event the number of them, how about something like this?

```
    public static string PopFrontPadded(ref string oStr, int iPadding)
    {

        // Argument check
        if (iPadding <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("iPadding <= 0");

        // Handle idiots
        if (oStr == null)
            return "".PadRight(iPadding);

        // Pop front & pad
        string oRes = new string(oStr.Take(Math.Min(oStr.Length, iPadding)).ToArray());
        oStr = oStr.Substring(oRes.Length);
        return oRes.PadRight(iPadding);
    }

    public static string format(string oSeparator, string oNewLine, string[] oStrings, int[] oWidths)
    {

        // Null checks
        if (oStrings == null || oWidths == null || oSeparator == null || oNewLine == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("oStrings == null || oWidths == null || oSeparator == null || oNewLine == null");

        // Length check: Must be same amount of widths as there are strings
        if (oStrings.Length != oWidths.Length)
            throw new ArgumentException("oStrings.Length != oWidths.Length");

        // All widths must be > 0
        foreach (int i in oWidths)
        {
            if (i <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("width must be > 0");
        }


        var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        List<string> oList = new List<string>(oStrings);

        // Loop while oList contains even one string with length > 0
        do
        {
            // For all given strings
            for (int i = 0; i < oList.Count; i++)
            {

                // PopFrontPadded
                string oTmp = oList[i];
                sb.Append(PopFrontPadded(ref oTmp, oWidths[i]));
                oList[i] = oTmp;

                // Append separator
                if (i < oList.Count - 1)
                    sb.Append(oSeparator);
            }

            // Append New Line
            sb.Append(oNewLine);

        } 
        while (oList.Find(x => x.Length > 0) != null); 

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        string text10 = "abcdefghij";
        string text15 = "123456789012345";
        string text6 = "zxywvu";

        string oResult = format(
            " ",                                      // Separator
            Environment.NewLine,                      // Line break
            new string[3] { text10, text15, text6 },  // strings
            new int[3]    {      4,     10,     5 }); // column widths

        Console.WriteLine(oResult);
        /* Outputs 
         *
         * abcd 1234567890 zxywv
         * efgh 12345      u    
         * ij                                
         *
         */
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it using LINQ:

```
string format(string column1, string column2, string column3)
    {
        int column1Width = 4;
        int column2Width = 10;
        int column3Width = 5;
        int loopCount = 0;

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        while (true)
        {
            string col1 = new string(column1.Skip<char>(loopCount * column1Width).Take<char>(column1Width).ToArray()).PadRight(column1Width);
            string col2 = new string(column2.Skip<char>(loopCount * column2Width).Take<char>(column2Width).ToArray()).PadRight(column2Width);
            string col3 = new string(column3.Skip<char>(loopCount * column3Width).Take<char>(column3Width).ToArray()).PadRight(column3Width);

            //Break out of loop once all col variables contain only white space
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(col1) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(col2) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(col3))
            {
                break;
            }

            output.AppendFormat("{0} {1} {2}\n", col1, col2, col3);
            loopCount++;
        }
        return output.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
string format(string col1, string col2, string col3)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    while(col1.Length > 4 || col2.Length > 10 || col3.Length > 5)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(CreateLine(ref col1, ref col2, ref col3));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

string CreateLine(ref string col1, ref string col2, ref string col3)
{
    var returnValue = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", 
                            col1.Substring(0, Math.Min(col1.Length, 4)).PadRight(4), 
                            col2.Substring(0, Math.Min(col2.Length, 10)).PadRight(10), 
                            col3.Substring(0, Math.Min(col3.Length, 5)).PadRight(5));
    if (col1.Length > 4) 
        col1 = col1.Substring(4, col1.Length - 4);
    if (col2.Length > 10) 
        col2 = col2.Substring(10, col2.Length - 10);
    if(col3.Length > 5)
        col3 = col3.Substring(5, col3.Length - 5);
    return returnValue;
}
```

**Notes:**
1. To display this properly you will have to use a monospace font like miriam fixed.
2. If you want to use this on an a browser you will either need to use `&nbps` instead of spaces or wrap the result with the `<pre>` tag.

Comment: this would work except in the case where col1 was 3 characters, col2 was 9 characters, and col3 was 4 characters... no?

Comment: I actually only tested the numbers in the qurstion, but I think it sould work with other lebgths as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
string text10 = "abcdefghij";
string text15 = "123456789012345";
string text6 = "zxywvu";
textBox_out.Font =
    new System.Drawing.Font("Monospac821 BT", 9F,
        System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular,
        System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
textBox_out.AppendText(
    string.format("{0,10} {1,15} {2,6}\r\n",text10,text15,text6));
```